# Android Studio Layout Error : an emulator

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I made a list of announcements with a list view.
Running the emulator brings down the list view. (RelativeLayout is in use, and the list view goes down when the emulator is running.)
I don't know what layout to use. I'd appreciate your help.

Corresponding xml source code:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/selected_item_textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="68dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="공지사항"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="71dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="-7dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/baseline_arrow_back_24" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_noti"
    style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="17dp" />


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvw"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="-1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-9dp" />
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnIXX.png)

I'd really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happening because of this property `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`. This aligns the view to the bottom of your parent which is `RelativeLayout`. Since the height of `RelativeLayout` is `match_parent` it fills the whole screen and put your `ListView` at bottom.

1. Remove the property `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` from your `ListView`. You might also want to remove `android:layout_centerVertical="true"`.
2. Make your`ListView` to be below the `selected_item_textview` using `layout_below` property.
3. You can adjust the margins as required.

```
 <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvw"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/selected_item_textview"
        android:layout_marginStart="-1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-9dp" />
```

Comment: I'm touched by your detailed reply! Thank you very much.

Comment: If it worked, Please mark the answer as accepted for support!

Comment: Thank you for your support. I answered your other question as well have a look.

Comment: I checked. You're a great developer. Thank you so much!